# What does the "$\cdot$" mean in an equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve an equation for a project that I am undertaking. The equation is very long and its probably not necessary to show it all here. Most of the equation is fairly straightforward; i.e., $1+(\frac{w}{W})(\frac{d}{t})$, etc. but at the very end it reads $\left(1+\frac{w}{W}\right)\left(\frac{D}{T}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{T}$.

$w$, $W$, $D$, and $T$ are all either constants or variables that I have solved already.
My question is, what is the "$\cdot$" symbol asking me to do?

In the equation in the book, the "$\cdot$" is in the centre of the dividing line between $1$ and $T$, as opposed to down low like a period or full stop.
I appreciate that I have phrased this question in an awkward manner, but as is obvious, I am no maths expert.

Here is a photo of the equation in the book:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the equation in the book that you could show?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have added a link to a photo of the equation in the book.

Comment: @PaulMulligan After looking at the photo, I can confirm that this means multiplication. As far as why it's there, I'm going to accuse bad typography. For instance, combining the factor of $2$ on the left and $\frac{1}{T}$ on the right into $\frac{2}{T}$ would be much clearer and take up less space.

Comment: Many thanks. Its as I presumed but couldnt be sure as it was the only instance of it in use in the book. If I am correct that the Fg and Cr are multiplied by each why would he not put a dot there ?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?
$$ \left(1+\frac{w}{W}\right)\left(\frac DT\right)\cdot\frac1T $$
That means multiply.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies.I presumed that it meant multiply but the rest of the equation just shows them beside each other to show that they should be multiplied - why would the dot be introduced only in that position ?

Comment: Sometimes that's done because the author sees some subtler grouping in the expression, like maybe the first few factors are conceptually related in some way that excludes the last one.  But sometimes it's done for no particular reason, or just because the author thinks it looks better for some inarticulable reason.  In this case, it might just be carelessness.  The dot is a bit too low; earlier in the line, the prime on $C_R'$ is way too high, and different from the placemet in the earlier text... maybe the author or publisher or whoever didn't understand their typesetting software.

Comment: Many thanks. Its a bit confusing to me why he would should multiplication in two different ways in the same equation.